# Problems installing enterprise .ipa

Tags: ipad, ios7, enterprise, ipa, failed-installation

All,

today I've experienced a problem while installing a enterprise build app.
I got a .ipa from my Jenkins build server just like I did a couple of times before and installing it on my own iPad mini was no problem.
But when my customer can over with their iPad mini, I failed to install the app.
I've added the .ipa to iTunes and connected it and clicked to install the app to the iPad. The icon appeared on the iPad, and the pie like circle started to rotate, but when it was half way, it stopped and the icon stayed dark grey.

So, it worked on one iOS 7 iPad mini, but on an other exactly the same type iPad and same .ipa file, it failed.

Does anyone has a suggestion what went wrong?

Regards EMA.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? Im having the same problem installing on ipad mini's.

Comment: mine, the other way around. only iPad mini doesn't work.